# Complex Socket Example

Tags: java, sockets, asynchronous, synchronous

have a complex socket question I was hoping that someone could point me in the direction of an example for.

I have a standard client/server synchronous message setup, clients make requests, and block until a response is received and everyone is happy.

however now i have the added requirement that over the synchronous channel, the client can subscribe to certain events, and when the server detects them, send them over asynchronously.  i thought the best way would be to open a second connection for each client when the client sends the subscription message (and server responds ack)  however I am having trouble finding an example online of this type of setup.  The client after subscription to some event, can continue sending/recv synchronous messages to the server, while also listening on socket2 for broadcast messages regarding the event its subscribed to.

What are some best practices here?

Thanks -

Comment: Sorry, but this is a wide topic; one that covers books and big tutorials. In other words: use your favorite search engine to find examples for such socket communications; chances are low that such a question will result in anything else but close requests and downvotes.

Comment: Please include some code, tell us what you've done so far, etc. Don't just ask for someone to write you a program. That's not the purpose of Stack Overflow.

Comment: I think he's just asking the classic question of "how can I have two blocking sockets on the same thread at the same time".

Comment: Instead of creating two sockets, you can use single one. Just detect a special sequence of bytes like `@@event@@messsge@@` when reading from the socket. When this sequence occurs you know that it's not normal data but an event message. This is a simple protocol that you would design for your program.

Comment: if i did this, i would constantly be blocking on the socket that is used for broadcasting data, which i do not want to be

Comment: @11thdimension No. You have to have a type and length prefix for every message, not just the callback messages. You can't just search random data for a random prefix. Any data can occur anywhere.

Comment: @EJP, you're right. It  can be done for a specific case where we are confident that this string will not be part of data, not in general.

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

1. Have each client socket run on it's own thread.  The "pros" of this solution is that it's easy to setup.  The "cons" are that unless you are both experienced and comfortable in a multi-threaded environment, the code can get buggy and complicated quickly.
2. Use a [selector](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-nio/selectors.html).  Probably what you want.  Best solution.

Comment: yeah i already have a selector on the server side, the question the client needs two sockets, but they may not be opened at the same time, and how to associate them together...

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at Netty: http://netty.io/

It supports synchronous and asynchronous sockets and comes with everything you need to build nice client/server applications without worrying about the plumbing too much.

Given the number of available libraries and frameworks out there, it probably isn't a good idea to roll your own implementation, unless it is a toy/learning project.